# Setting Ubuntu resolution to 5120x2160

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I have a new monitor that can display at 5120x2160,
See:
https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/dell-ultrasharp-40-curved-wuhd-monitor-u4021qw/apd/210-ayjf/monitors-monitor-accessories.

I have ran

```
cvt 5120 2160
```

Then

```
xrandr --newmode "5120x2160_60.00"  949.00  5120 5536 6096 7072  2160 2163 2173 2237 -hsync +vsync
```

And then

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 "5120x2160_60.00"
```

Then to test its working I run

```
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 5120x2160
```

And get ..

```
xrandr: cannot find mode 5120x2160
```

I have spent far to much time on this and even bough a new high end HDMI cable thinking that could be the problem. Check on my windows machine and the resolution works perfect with plug and play, just can not get it on ubuntu.

Ubuntu is being a pain and the max resolution im gettimg (plug and play) at 21:9 is 2560x1440.

can anyone help me push it to 5120x2160.

thank you.

UPDATE:

run though commands again trying out a different resolution and can successfully get 3440x1440 @30 running, but no ball on 5120x2160.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Which nvidia driver?

Comment: @David configuration: driver=i915 latency=0

Comment: The version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: @David Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-71-generic

Comment: It doesn't support 60Hz at the native resolution over HDMI, only 30Hz: *WUHD 5120 x 2160 (DisplayPort: 60 Hz, HDMI: 30 Hz)*. Source: https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/dell-ultrasharp-40-curved-wuhd-monitor-u4021qw/apd/210-ayjf/monitors-monitor-accessories#techspecs_section

Comment: @ChanganAuto ive tried to set to 30Hz still no game

Comment: 5120x2160_30.00  29.98  still no luck

Answer (score 0):

you typed xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 5120x2160
it should be

```
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode "5120x2160_60.00"
```

That should help.

Comment: Unfortunately I get '$ xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 5120x2160
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed'

Answer (score 0):

I got the same panel in my Levono P40W-20 and have it working with 30Hz. cvt needs 30 as third argument in order to generate the correct modeline for 30Hz:

```
cvt 5120 2160 30
xrandr --newmode "5120x2160_30.00"  452.75  5120 5448 5992 6864  2160 2163 2173 2200 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 "5120x2160_30.00"
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode "5120x2160_30.00"
```